# get longitude from position coords

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I cannot retrieve data from longitude. Statically it works, but if I use the variable `currentLatLng.longitutde`, I get `null`.
This is my code :

```
var currentLatLng = position.coords;
var latlon = "Latitude" + currentLatLng.latitude + ","
             + "Longitude" + currentLatLng.longitutde;
var mappOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatLng.latitude,
                                   currentLatLng.longitutde),
    //center: new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatLng.latitude, 10.181531600000001),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mappOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is longitude, not longitutde.

Answer (score 0):

keep attention from autocomplete it's longitude, not longitutde
[image]

Comment: That the autocomplete misspells it means that you misspelt it somewhere else too.